# Derby run sql script by redirecting standardIO

Tags: sql, derby, io-redirection

I have the following join.sql script:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:barra';
show tables;
create table sp500_univ as
select a.*,b.* from (select * from LEFT_SIDE) as a
left join (select * from RIGHT_SIDE) as b
on a.cmp_flg = b.cmp_flg2;
disconnect;
exit;
```

which I run with the following command:

```
 java org.apache.derby.tools.ij < join.sql
```

and get the following output:

```
java org.apache.derby.tools.ij < join.sql
ij version 10.14
ij> ij> TABLE_SCHEM         |TABLE_NAME                    |REMARKS
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
APP                 |LEFT_SIDE                     |
APP                 |RIGHT_SIDE                    |

2 rows selected
ij> > > > ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 4, column 25.
Issue the 'help' command for general information on IJ command syntax.
Any unrecognized commands are treated as potential SQL commands and executed directly.
Consult your DBMS server reference documentation for details of the SQL syntax supported by your server.
ij> ij>
```

If I run this sql right from the command line in IJ it works.

Comment: Not sure what operating system you're on, but try `type join.sql` or `cat join.sql` right before you run your script, just to be very certain that the file has exactly the contents that you expect it to have. Also look for special characters in the file; perhaps your editor has inserted something at line 4, column 25?

Answer (score 0):

apparently when running from a file you can't create tables and load data from a select statement.  You need to add the WITH NO DATA.  The WITH DATA option has not yet been implemented. From Derby's documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE ... AS ...
With the alternate form of the CREATE TABLE statement, the column names and/or the 
column data types can be specified by providing a query. The columns in the query 
result are used as a model for creating the columns in the new table.

If no column names are specified for the new table, then all the columns in the 
result of the query expression are used to create same-named columns in the new 
table, of the corresponding data type(s). If one or more column names are specified 
for the new table, then the same number of columns must be present in the result of 
the query expression; the data types of those columns are used for the corresponding 
columns of the new table.

The WITH NO DATA clause specifies that the data rows which result from evaluating the 
query expression are not used; only the names and data types of the columns in the 
query result are used. The WITH NO DATA clause must be specified; in a future 
release, Derby may be modified to allow the WITH DATA clause to be provided, which 
would indicate that the results of the query expression should be inserted into the 
newly-created table. In the current release, however, only the WITH NO DATA form of t 
the statement is accepted.
```